# How can I perserve the order of elements in a list of lists

Tags: python

suppose I have a list

```
lst1 = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]]
```

and another list

```
lst2 = [['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)], ['b', (2, 1)], ['b', (2, 2)]]
```

Now How can I make sure that in lst1 every sequence should be as it is, which means there is no (1,2) before (1,1) or (2,3) before (2,2)

and how can make sure that this order is preserved in lst2 which means ['a', (1,2)] should not come before ['a', (1,1)] or ['b',(2,2)] should not come before ['b', (2,1)]

Comment: What happens to the tuples that start with '3'? Do they go to a 'c'? in lst2? Where do those *partitions* 'a', 'b'... come from?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how does simply sorting the lists differ from what you want?

Comment: Have you thought of using objects and implementing `__cmp__` ?

Comment: yes the tuples that start with '3' go with 'c'. I have to make sure something that could be preserve the ordering for the two lists with different patterns

Comment: Are we doing your programming assignments here? **:-D**. Hey, nothing wrong with that for me... You can ask whatever you want wherever you want! (unless otherwise told by your teachers) I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1):

`lst1[0].sort(key=lambda tpl: tpl[0]*10 + tpl[1])` should do the trick.

You can adept this for `lst2` aswell: `lst2.sort(key=lambda lst: lst[1][0]*10 + lst[1][1])`

**Edit:**

The order you want to achieve is apperently the natural order. Therefore `lst1[0].sort()` and `lst2.sort()` will sort the lists as stated in your question.

Comment: how does this order differ from `sorted(lst1[0])` and `sorted(lst2)`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I wasnt aware that this equals the natural order. I will test itout tommorow and edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own "`compare`" function and play with that.

For instance, with lst2

```
lst2 = [['a', (1, 1)], ['a', (1, 2)], ['a', (1, 3)], ['b', (2, 1)], ['b', (2, 2)]]

def compareLst2(item1, item2):
    retval = 0
    retval = ord(item1[0])  - ord(item2[0]) 
    if retval == 0:
        for i in range(2):
            retval=item1[1][i] - item2[1][i]
            if retval != 0:
                return retval
    return retval

print sorted(lst2 , cmp=compareLst2)
```

Takes the ascii code of the character in the first position. (`'a' < 'b'`). If they're equal, checks the first number in the tuple (the second position), if they're equal, checks the second number in the tuple... (the '*tuple*' is `itemWhatever[1]`)

This is a bit... well... stupid method, since you don't need to get the `ord` to sort characters but you get the idea, right?

Comment: cmp is deprecated and was replaced by key